# Automatic show ajax loader gif image when any ajax function is called in the application

Tags: jquery, preloader

I have many ajax calls in the application which are performing various operations,
I am searching for a Jquery plugin or any other method which will detect any ajax call
made and show loading image when operation is in process and hide it after operation is complete.Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a solution for this , I used  [Pretty Loader](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyloader/) and my problem is solved .

Comment: just need to call a function jQuery.prettyLoader(); and it detects  ajax call and show/hide the image before and after operation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    ShowLoading(1);
});
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    ShowLoading(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).beforeSend(function() {
    /* show loader */
}).success(function(){
    /* hide loader */
});
```

Comment: i have more than 200 ajax call in my application, i doesn't seems logical to go an write hide(),show() function in each one of those.